# Remove image set by Glide and use imageView.setImageBitmap()

Tags: android, imageview, android-imageview, android-glide

I have a fragment where at first an Image is set to an imageView using Glide (image url fetched from internet). Then upon click on the imageview a new image can be chose from either gallery or camera intent. the problem is when I try to set the bitmap that I get from OnActivityResult(). The image actually sets but that is overlapped by glide. I need to show image captured from camera/gallery. Any help is appreciated, also if it can be done using Picasso or any other library please suggest that.
  Below is what I have tried so far

the onActivityResult ()

```
 @Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
{
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK)
    {
        if (requestCode == SELECT_FILE)
            onSelectFromGalleryResult(data);
        else if (requestCode == REQUEST_CAMERA)
            //   onCaptureImageResult((Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data"));
            onCaptureImageResult(data);
    }
}

private void onCaptureImageResult(Intent data)
{
    if (data != null)
    {
        mImageUri = Uri.parse("file://" + data.getStringExtra(CameraConfiguration.Arguments.FILE_PATH));
    }

    try
    {
        bitmap_image = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(mContext.getContentResolver(), mImageUri);
        ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bitmap_image.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 60, bytes);

        bitmap_image = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap_image, (int) (bitmap_image.getWidth() * 0.5), (int) (bitmap_image.getHeight() * 0.5), true);

        ExifInterface ei = new ExifInterface(data.getStringExtra(CameraConfiguration.Arguments.FILE_PATH));
        int orientation = ei.getAttributeInt(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION, ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_UNDEFINED);

        switch (orientation)
        {
            case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90:
                bitmap_image = (SnappyUtils.rotateImage(bitmap_image, 90));
                break;

            case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_180:
                bitmap_image = (SnappyUtils.rotateImage(bitmap_image, 180));
                break;

            case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_270:
                bitmap_image = (SnappyUtils.rotateImage(bitmap_image, 270));
                break;

            case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL:

            default:
                break;
        }
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.d("exception", e.toString());
    }
    ////////////////////// it is showing on iv_logo2 as expected as it does not has anything set by glide//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    iv_logo.setBackground(null);
    iv_logo.setImageBitmap(bitmap_image);
    iv_logo2.setImageBitmap(bitmap_image);

    ///////////////////////////tried added this by seeing other SO posts //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    Glide.with(mContext)
            .load(mImageUri)
            .signature(new StringSignature(String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis())))
            .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.NONE)
            .skipMemoryCache(true)
            .into(iv_logo);
}
```

Also please note that this is not the same issue as removing cache of Glide

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After spending lots of time figuring out how to remove image set by Glide, and failing, decided to go old-school and first download the image in phone and set that image as bitmap in my application

asynchtask to download image

```
private class GetImages extends AsyncTask<Object, Object, Object>
{
    private String requestUrl, imagename_;
    private ImageView view;
    private Bitmap bitmap;
    private FileOutputStream fos;

    private GetImages(String requestUrl, ImageView view, String _imagename_)
    {
        this.requestUrl = requestUrl;
        this.view = view;
        this.imagename_ = _imagename_;
    }

    @Override
    protected Object doInBackground(Object... objects)
    {
        try
        {
            URL url = new URL(requestUrl);
            URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
            bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(conn.getInputStream());
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Object o)
    {
        view.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 12):

Use:

```
Glide.with(iv_logo.context)
    .clear(iv_logo);
```

Comment: While this might answer the authors question, it lacks some explaining words and/or links to documentation.Raw code snippets are not very helpful without some phrases around them. You may also find how to write a [good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) very helpful.

Comment: Actually I think its very clever. This answer is exactly what the question asks for.

Answer (score 0):

update your code
edit:

```
iv.logo.setBackground(null);
```

to:

```
iv.logo.setImageBitmap(null);
```

Comment: not working, do you know how to remove image set by glide?